# Xcode 4.5 File Templates - Insert E-mail Address/Website?

Tags: xcode, templates

I've been trying to edit the source code file templates in Xcode 4.5 (inside app bundle), to achieve this more doxygen-friendly header comment format:

```
/*!
    @file ___FILENAME___

    @package ___PROJECTNAME___

    @brief

    @details

    @author ___FULLUSERNAME___ | ___EMAIL___ | ___WEBSITE___

    @date ___DATE___

    @version

    @copyright ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.

    @section License
*/
```

At first, I was using the old method of editing the defaults (either by command line or editing the com.apple.Xcode.plist file in Xcode's built in plist editor), but the changes aren't applied - even after restarting Xcode. I hoped to edit `ORGANIZATIONNAME`, and add my own `EMAIL` and `WEBSITE` fields (see code above).

I read somewhere that `ORANIZATIONNAME` is now entered on the Xcode GUI, on a per-project basis, so I got that one working. But I still wish to expand `___EMAIL___` and `___WEBSITE___`, either from preset defaults or (better) from my address book. Is this possible?